# popup login page reload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

i use fancybox for popup the login page

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".spop").fancybox({
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'speedIn': 400,
        'speedOut': 200,
        'width': 320,
        'height': 315,
        'padding': 0,
        'margin': 0,
        'titleShow': false,
        'scrolling': 'no',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'overlayShow': true,
        'onClosed': function () {
            parent.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
```

---

as you see i use event 'onClosed': function () { parent.location.reload(true);

but i need to do this event but under some condition

if the user click close i need  fancebox don't reload you can find this issues in this link 
http://www.aqar4me.com/rent.aspx

---

[image]

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add to mention when you do want the reload, and when not. You could put a condition in the onclose method right?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function instead of your current,

```
function reloadParentPage() {
var selfUrl = unescape(parent.window.location.pathname);
parent.location.reload(true);

parent.window.location.replace(selfUrl);

parent.window.location.href = selfUrl;
```

}

It will help you.

Comment: thnxxxxxx but the page still reload

Comment: if you don't want to reload the page just write the code parent.location.reload(false);

Answer (score 0):

You use the following code

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

instead of using `parent.location.reload(true);`

Comment: hi universal :) 
do you mean that i remove the event onClosed
and just in sign in click use (parent.location.reload(true);)